# What are the functions of the different characters in HTML?

Tags: html, character

I was wondering how the different HTML characters (>,<,",:,;, etc..) worked, as in, what each one does. My instructor told me that it was crucial that I learn the order in which to place characters in a bit of code, but he never told me why they belong in that order. I feel that shedding some light on how the characters work will not only give myself insight, but also give insight to others as to why placement of certain characters in code is so important.

Comment: They're not really crucial any more in this day and age, but it doesn't *hurt* to know them. Can you clarify what exactly you are asking about though? You should have some sort of table on what each one does, i.e. which entity code creates which character

Comment: Forgive me, I meant what each individual character means in terms of html formatting.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you make an example?

Comment: I re-worded the question, I hope that helps?

Comment: Oh, you don't mean the entities, but the control characters themselves. Well those are part of HTML's syntax, are you already familiar with that? They have no meaning really except that they make up HTML's basic syntax

Comment: If you mean how the elements work then sort of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check out something like this http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/html_cheatsheet/

`<` says "This is the beginning of an HTML tag"

`>` says "This is the end of an HTML tag, anything after this is content"

`</` says "This is the beginning of a closing HTML tag" i.e. `</p>`

`/>` is a self-closing tag like img, link, or br, for a tag that doesn't have a separate closing tag (not entirely necessary but good to know about)

`=` is how you pair attributes and values, like `type="text"` or `src="img.jpg"`

```
<!-- is a comment and will hide its contents -->
```

`:` and `;` are for CSS not HTML, though sometimes they are used inline.  like `style="display:none;"`.  "display" is the property, and "none" is the value so `:` is like `=` in HTML, and the `;` means the end of the property/value pair.

I wish I could tell you more about why they are this way, but that's like asking why a period means the end of the sentence.  It just does.

Good luck!

Comment: I will also add that learning these is incredibly important, because a misplaced semicolon or closing bracket can waste a huuge amount of your time.  I know for even very good developers who have been at it for years, they still will spend hours trying to fix a bug only to realize they were missing a semicolon.

Comment: Thank you, this was an extremely helpful response!

Comment: In case you want to know a little about the history of the period's meaning at the end of the sentence, here's that too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop#History

Answer (score 0):

The markup-significant characters such as “<” have no meaning as such, only as constituents of larger expressions. So it is generally impossible to learn their meanings except in the context of learning the meaningful expressions, like the syntax of tags.

Their use somewhat varies by HTML version.

Listing them down would hardly serve a useful purpose, except as regards to the need for escaping them when they are to be used as data characters: “<” and “&” need to be escaped in text content, “&” in attribute values too. That’s it. Well, within an attribute value, you cannot use the attribute value delimiter " or ' inside the attribute value.

For example, although “=” has a special role in attribute specifications, it has this role in that context only. In element content, it can be used as such.